# Worshipping or worshipper?

Tags: adjectives, nouns, compounds

What’s the difference between the sentences given below?

> He is a God-worshipping.
>
> He is a God worshipper.

To my knowledge the first one (God-worshipping) is a compound adjective, but I can’t distinguish.

Comment: You've identified the difference - one's an adjective and one's a noun.  What can't you distinguish?

Comment: Juhasz, their meanings

Comment: They suggest the same meaning, but the first one is not a grammatically complete sentence.   The adjective doesn't describe anything.  It would need to be *He is a God-worshipping **man**.*  (or God-worshipping baker, or God-worshipping father, or whatever)

Comment: stevekeiretsu,  I have seen in a religious book “He is all-knowing”

Comment: But you would not see 'He is _an_  all-knowing.'

Comment: Kate Bunting, hmmm! Thanks to the people who corrected me! I learned a new thing today!

Comment: Kate Bunting, you are so expert!!!

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between those sentences is that one is grammatically correct, and the other is not.

> He is a God-worshipping.

This is wrong, because (as you've correctly noted), "God-worshipping" is an *adjective*, not a noun.  "is" can take either an adjective or a noun, but when using an adjective, you cannot use an article ("a"/"an"/"the"), because articles are only used with nouns.  Therefore, this should be:

> He is God-worshipping.

As for the difference between "God-worshipping" and "a God worshipper", "God-worshipping is the adjective form and "God worshipper" is the noun form.  "God-worshipping" is used to modify other nouns:

> a God-worshipping **person**
>   a God-worshipping **father**

(etc)

Whereas, "God worshipper" is its own noun:

> **A God worshipper** is the same thing as **a God-worshipping person**.

Comment: Foogod, can’t we omit ‘One’?  The first (one) is correct and the second as well.

Comment: @JayHo You can in that case, but that is something that can be done with numbers (and a couple of other special cases), not with all adjectives in general.  Saying "the first" instead of "the first one" is fine, but you cannot, for example, say "the red".  You must say "the red one".

Comment: Foogod, “He is a God-worshipping” seems fine to me because in the Quran I have read “Our Lord! Accept (this service) from us: For Thou art the All-Hearing, the All-knowing.” If it’s possible to use ‘the’ then why can’t we use ‘a’ instead of The in that example?

Comment: Religious texts like the Bible or the Quran are not necessarily the best examples to draw from for current English grammar.  Many translations contain archaic or heavily stylized forms which don't apply to everyday English.  In the case of your example, "the *(adjective)*" is a form that is often applied to God or sometimes other highly-elevated individuals (such as a king or emperor) as a form of tribute speech, which is why it is used there, but it only works in that context, and even then it's a bit old-fashioned sounding.

Comment: Foogod, thanks for your valuable time! I agree it’s a bit old-fashioned sound, but are you sure “he is a God-worshipping” is incorrect? I am not so expert at the English language. I also read some sentences something like, “You are receiving the Quran from an All-Wise, All-Knowing”.

Comment: To be absolutely clear:  Yes, I am sure, it is definitely wrong.  It is ungrammatical (it violates grammar rules) and unidiomatic (it sounds wrong).  If you try to say that anybody who hears it will think you don't know how to speak English properly.  I would actually say that your "You are receiving..." example is also wrong.  Whoever said it does not speak English properly.

Comment: The Quran and the Bible were translated by experts.

Comment: Do you know in what situation “You are receiving...” was used in the Quran?